# Why can C#'s System.Convert convert (string) to (int), but not (string) to (int?)?

Tags: c#, casting, nullable

If I run the following code:

`(int)Convert.ChangeType("3", typeof(int))`

The result is `3`. Awesome.

If I change it to:

`(int?)Convert.ChangeType("3", typeof(int?))`

The result is

> Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.Nullable`1
>   [[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'.

However, it handles this just fine:

`(int?)Convert.ChangeType("3", typeof(int))`

Why can't it handle the conversion to a nullable int type directly?

Comment: "Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.Nullable`1" - ChangeType just don't know how to convert String to Nullable<T>.

Comment: This limitation is [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08.aspx): *The `ChangeType(Object, Type)` method can convert a nullable type to another type. However, it cannot convert another type to a value of a nullable type, even if `conversionType` is the underlying type of the `Nullable<T>`.To perform the conversion, you can use a casting operator (in C#) or a conversion function (in Visual Basic).*

Comment: `3` is an `int`, anyway, not a `Nullable<int>`

Comment: Maybe that's not what you are looking for, but you could use TryParse(String, Int32) and check the return.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Convert.ChangeType` long predates nullable values in .NET, so it couldn't have been a hack. There's very little reason to use `Convert` nowadays.

Why is this a hack? Well, you're asking `Convert` to perform multiple conversions in a row, while also realizing that a wrong value should be represented as `null` in the "real" return value. Multiple implicit conversions never happen in .NET. `int` and `int?` are completely separate types, and it's only the C# compiler that makes you think they work well together - it's all just syntax sugar. Syntax sugar doesn't work when you're just calling a random method that returns `object` :)

If you need this functionality, just write your own wrapper that always returns a nullable.